# neo4j movie example, change all node titles to node names

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have a bunch of actors and movies in my database.  The movies have titles and I want to convert all the properties that have title as their property name to be "name".  Would like to do this via cypher.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start n=node(*)
where has(n.title)
set n.name = n.title
delete n.title
return count(*);
```